# How to draw Star-Shaped Pentagon graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I was showing cycle $C_{5}$ is isomorphic star shaped pentagon. But I am not able to draw star shaped pentagon in *Mathematica*. I tried with many packages but I am not getting desired shape. For example

```
options = Sequence[VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.7, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {1/2, 1/2}], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[16, Black, Bold], 
   GraphLayout -> "RandomEmbedding", ImageSize -> 250, 
   EdgeStyle -> Black];
Graph[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> d, d <-> e, e <-> a}, options]
```

Instead of random embedding which one should I use to get a star shaped pentagon?

Comment: It be easier to read if you use the code tag in the editor to duplicate the code in the blog.

Comment: @JoseECalderon Now it's kooks better. Thank you

Comment: `CirculantGraph[5, 2]`?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Yes it's working . Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that the *connectivity* you specify won't lead to a star shaped graph, but perhaps I am missing the point.

For instance, however, remove the `GraphEmbedding` altogether to simplify the comparison:

```
options = 
 Sequence[
   VertexStyle -> White, VertexSize -> 0.7, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {1/2, 1/2}], 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[16, Black, Bold], ImageSize -> 250, EdgeStyle -> Black
 ];
```

and compare the following two graphs:

```
Graph[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> d, d <-> e, e <-> a}, options]  (* yours *)
```

[image: pentagon]

```
Graph[{a, b, c, d, e}, {a <-> c, c <-> e, e <-> b, b <-> d, d <-> a}, options]
```

[image: star]

---

For further inspiration, you can also take a look at the `Graph` object produced by `CirculantGraph[5, 2]`, as suggested by @Quantum_Oli in [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130194/how-to-draw-star-shaped-pentagon-graph/130232#comment351540_130194):

```
CirculantGraph[5, 2] // InputForm

(* Out:
Graph[
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
 {1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5}, 
 {GraphLayout -> {"VertexLayout" -> "CircularEmbedding", "PackingLayout" -> None}}
]
*)
```

Comment: In general for any star shaped polygon I think removing embedding may work right ?

Answer (score 4):

First remove  `GraphLayout` from your `options`:

```
options2 = FilterRules[{options}, Except[GraphLayout]];

g1 = Graph[{a <-> b, b <-> c, c <-> d, d <-> e, e <-> a}, options2]
```

[image]

Two additional approaches:

1. You can use a re-ordered vertex list as the first argument of `Graph`:
2. You can re-order the vertex coordinates to place the vertices to form a star

The first approach gives

```
Graph[VertexList[g1][[{1, 4, 2, 5, 3}]], EdgeList[g1], options2]
```

[image]

And the second approach, using the same re-ordering to the vertex coordinates of `g1`:

```
SetProperty[g1, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g1][[{1, 4, 2, 5, 3}]]]
```

[image]